# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value uint32 swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When I try to set my results label to this string containing a UInt32 my app crashes and I get the error message "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

I figured that meant I just have to add a ! to the variable but when I try that I get the issue "Operand should have optional type, has type UInt32.

```
var fingers = arc4random_uniform(6)

result.text = "Incorrect, I am holding up \(fingers) fingers"
```

Comment: try checking what result is ;) i guess it it is nil...

Comment: It is, but I'm assigning it in that statement so shouldn't that make it not nil before it errors out?

Comment: i am talking about `result`, not the `text`. If `result` is nil, you first need to assign it something, maybe show more code, where is result declared and defined?

Comment: As @luk2302 said, there must be a problem with `result` (UILabel?). `arc4random_uniform` does not return Optional, so you can be sure that there is some value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will surely work:

```
var result: UILabel = UILabel()
var fingers: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(6)

result.text = "Incorrect, I am holding up \(fingers) fingers"

println("\(result.text)")
```